# How to draw unicode characters on transparent image in PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, imaging

I am trying to draw certain unicode characters on and image using python (PIL to be precise).

Using the following code I can generate the images with a white background:

('entity_code' is passed in to the method)

```
    size = self.font.getsize(entity_code)
    im = Image.new("RGBA", size, (255,255,255))
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
    draw.text((0,6), entity_code, font=self.font, fill=(0,0,0))
    del draw
    img_buffer = StringIO()
    im.save(img_buffer, format="PNG")
```

I tried the following:

('entity_code' is passed in to the method)

```
    img = Image.new('RGBA',(100, 100))
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
    draw.text((0,6), entity_code, fill=(0,0,0), font=self.font)
    img_buffer = StringIO()
    img.save(img_buffer, 'GIF', transparency=0)
```

This however fails to draw the unicode character. It looks like I end up with an empty transparent image :(

What am I missing here? Is there a better way to draw text on a transparent image in python?

Answer (score 2):

Your code examples are all over the place, and I am inclined to agree with @fraxel that you are not being specific enough in the usage of fill colors and the background colors for your RGBA images. However I can't actually get your code example to work at all because I don't really have any idea of how your code fits together.

Also, just like @monkut mentioned you need to look at the font you are using because your font may not support specific unicode characters. However unsupported characters should be drawn as a empty square (or whatever the default value is) so you would at least see some kind of output.

I have created a simple example below that draws unicode characters and saves them to a .png file.

```
import Image,ImageDraw,ImageFont

# sample text and font
unicode_text = u"Unicode Characters: \u00C6 \u00E6 \u00B2 \u00C4 \u00D1 \u220F"
verdana_font = ImageFont.truetype("verdana.ttf", 20, encoding="unic")

# get the line size
text_width, text_height = verdana_font.getsize(unicode_text)

# create a blank canvas with extra space between lines
canvas = Image.new('RGB', (text_width + 10, text_height + 10), (255, 255, 255))

# draw the text onto the text canvas, and use black as the text color
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(canvas)
draw.text((5,5), unicode_text, font = verdana_font, fill = "#000000")

# save the blank canvas to a file
canvas.save("unicode-text.png", "PNG")
```

The code above creates the png displayed below:
[image: unicode text]

As a side note, I am using Pil 1.1.7 and Python 2.7.3 on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to make sure that your loaded font supports the characters your trying to output.

An example here:
http://blog.wensheng.com/2006/03/how-to-create-images-from-chinese-text.html

```
font = ImageFont.truetype('simsun.ttc',24)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your examples you create a `RGBA` image, but you don't specify the value of the `alpha` channel (so it defaults to 255). If you replace `(255, 255, 255)` with `(255,255,255,0)` it should work ok (as pixels with 0 alpha are transparent).

To illustrate:

```
import Image
im = Image.new("RGBA", (200,200), (255,255,255))
print im.getpixel((0,0))
im2 = Image.new("RGBA", (200,200), (255,255,255,0))
print im2.getpixel((0,0))
#Output:
(255, 255, 255, 255)
(255, 255, 255, 0)
```